# blender as module , will it suffice?

Tags: python, particles, physics, fluid-simulation

I'm doing a simulation project with two colleagues in university in which we'll simulate a star(it's a physics project).
we're considering building blender from source as python module and use the module in c# program.

### requirements

the module should help us in these things:
1-nebula drawing(physics of smoke is optional).
2-star formation(the accumulating and pressing etc, physics will be done by us but we must make sure that the particle system will help us).
3-gravity and pressure.
4-color(the color depends on mass, again we can calculate the color by our hands but blender should be able to apply the color we've calculated not on every particle but on the star).
5-explosion.
6-diffrential rotation: rotation must vary by latitude and distance from center, the rotation effect on the star is optional but the rotation itself is required.
7-can be used easily(at least as easy as using python module in c# can be) in winforms c# and can be told on what window will the draw be.

### Question

and the real question is : can the requirements be met ?

### PS

we were using dpsf with xna but when tried dpsf, it seems it doesn't do physics, and that's not our propose.
of course we don't want to use the program as we're afraid of university policy things, but using a library and programming yourself is definitely legal.